# How to display random background image with modern, vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What I've tried so far:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const headerBackImg = document.querySelector("#header");
  const imgArr = [
    "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
    "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0011ff/000000",
  ];
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
  headerBackImg.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(0,0,0,0.25)),url(${imgArr[randNum]})`;
}, false);
```

```css
#header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

I've also tried using variables instead of constants and double quotes instead of tildes.

Comment: Are you trying to add both linear gradient and an image?

Comment: You' re code is working, as demonstrated by my edit which contains your JS code with missing HTML and suitable CSS added and image URLs replaced. It displays a random image whenever you reload the page. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Mushroomator – Hmm, I wonder if it's a caching/loading issue then. Is there a better way to make absolutely sure the page is fully loaded before executing my script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.